# Lambda for Groupby and Sum?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

```
var product = db.Products
                .Where(x => x.ProductKey == 310)
                .Join(db.InternetSales, p => p.ProductKey,
                       c => c.ProductKey, (p, c) => c)
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

This is my query but I dont know how to group it by ProductName and Sum the Sales Amount.

Comment: Please pay attention to the post preview when asking a question - very long lines are much harder to read than adding some line breaks to your code (as I've now done). Next, it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, given that you're ending up with a single result...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var product = db.Products.Where(x => x.ProductKey == 310)
                 .Join(db.InternetSales, p => p.ProductKey, 
                       c => c.ProductKey, (p, c) => c)
                 .GroupBy(c => c.ProductName)
                 .Select(g => new { g.Key, TotalSales = g.Sum(x => x.Sales) })
                 .SingleOrDefault();
```

Or if you *only* need the sum, try this:

```
 var totalSales = db.Products.Where(x => x.ProductKey == 310)
                    .Join(db.InternetSales, p => p.ProductKey, 
                          c => c.ProductKey, (p, c) => c)
                    .GroupBy(c => c.ProductName)
                    .SingleOrDefault()
                    .Sum(x => x.Sales);
```

Comment: okay thank you very much but i got problem here :The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType4`2[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'BikeSales.BikeSaleDatabase.InternetSale'.

Comment: @KenginVeron That's an conflict between your declared view model type (if you're using razor, that's the `@model InternetSale` at the top of the .cshtml file) and the view model you passed in from your controller through the `View` method. I'd need a fair amount more information about your controller and view to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Join` at all, because you already have `ProductKey` which is then used to join `InternetSales` table.

I think you can end up with following:

```
var TotalSales = db.InternetSales
                   .Where(s => s.ProductKey == 310)
                   .Select(s => s.Sales)
                   .Sum();
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g It's not supported in all version of LINQ to Entities: [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)